# What is the meaning of "studied a favorite philosopher" in this text?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> In the silence of his tent, as he **studied a favorite philosopher** during the dead of night, he thought he saw the Genius of the State, with veiled head and cornucopia, stealing away through the hangings slowly and sadly.

[The Seven Great Monarchies, by George Rawlinson](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/16167/16167-h/16167-h.htm)

In this sentence, does the bold section mean he studied a book of a favorite philosopher?

Comment: Please could you include your research?

Comment: If the person had kidnapped the philosopher, and tied them up in his tent, then the phrase would be quite literal …

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course - he was studying *the works of* a philosopher he admired.

In the given context, this almost certainly means that he was studying a book by that philosopher, but, in a different context, it could also include studying books and other published materials *about* that philosopher, participating in discussions on related topics, and so forth.

Comment: Kate, this is in the low quality queue

Comment: @marcellothearcane Do you mean that my answer is of low quality? I can't win. Not long ago I was criticised for answering questions in comments.

Comment: Not at all! I know the feeling :) Just letting you know, I haven't voted to delete or anything bad.

Comment: The 'close-vote when very obviously not a question suitable for a site aimed at linguists + add an answer in comments' option was still available last time I looked on Meta. Here, there is no sign of research (a dictionary would almost certainly give a parallel example under 'study') and "Is 'They were studying Freud' correct?" is probably more of an ELL standard. But this answer doesn't provide a reference licensing the metonymy either.